# Как далать опред. действия через некоторое время в JS?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть бесконечный цикл while. После входа в этот цикл мне надо делать определённые действия через некоторое время. Как это можно реализовать?

```
//какой-то код
while (true) {
  //какой-то код
  //без цикла while нельзя он нужен для самой программы. Вход в него обязателен
}
```

Comment: нероботает - робот в забастовке?

Comment: это слишком пространное определение. конкретно пишите код и конкретно что не работает

Comment: Я имею виду как это сделать(реализовать)? То есть "Как после входа в цикл мне делать определённые действия через некоторое время"

Comment: Пример: После входа в бесконечный цикл while (true). Мне надо делать 2 клика (click(x, y)) каждые 30 сек.

Comment: где ваш код, который *нероботает*. Что-то не вижу его в вопросе

Comment: чтобы делать 2 клика (click(x, y)) каждые 30 сек  цикл  while (true) не нужен. нужно только setInterval.

Comment: Прочитайте пожалуйста. Я правил вопрос

Comment: интересно, а что у вас вообще внутри while(true)? Просто бесконечные циклы - это же редко реально требуется подобное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого? Пример с интервалом в 3 секунды.

```js
const interval = 3 * 1000;
let nextTime = Date.now() + interval;

while (true) {
  //какой-то код

  if (Date.now() > nextTime) {
    nextTime += interval;
    console.log('Interval passed.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо вам большое. Выручили:)

Answer (score 0):

как-то так

```
//code
console.clear();
let flag = true;
let i = 0;
while(i++ < 10){
  if (flag) {
    flag = false;
    setInterval(()=>console.log('click'), 5000);
    setTimeout(()=>console.log('click once'), 30000)
  }
  //code
}
console.log('end');
```

Comment: Тоже спасибо за ответ, но я возьму другой

Comment: если цикл while достаточно быстро выполняется то другой ответ лучше, а если он не стабильно или долго выполняется то лучше этот.